# How to enable timeline view in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Timeline view has come recently for VS code updates and show history of the file changes but i accidentally click hide or some place and it got hidden. How to bring that back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an bug in VS code and yet to be fixed. If it is not fixed for your version, you can remove the **timeline.excludeSources** setting from your user settings, and that should restore the view.

> To find user settings you can Ctrl + Shift + Q and find Preferences:
> Open User Settings. There search for timeline and remove the key
> value.

Answer (score 13):

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+E and it will open Explore Tab to the left (which shows all the files & folders in the current directory).
2. Click the three dots on the right, as shown in picture and click Timeline to enable Timeline tab..[image]

Comment: This works, once the timeline's view has been set to its default position (at the bottom of the editor).  But for me it was in the secondary panel - right clicking on the timeline icon and resetting its position to the default made everything work.

Answer (score 8):

Context-Click (Right-Click) on the title bar of the View container and select the View that you have removed.

Or choose command `View: Reset View Locations`

Comment: Hi @rioV8 thanks for your suggestion. Can you please vote up my answer if that also works for you?

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue where all of a sudden the timeline tab is missing.

Comment: Your second answer probably would have helped me, but I didn't know enough about VSCode..  Instead, the timeline was in the secondary panel, and by right-clicking on the timeline icon I got the option to reset the view location.

Answer (score 0):

After not seeing it after trying several of these solutions...  I finally saw that timeline was its own view in the side panel.  There, right clicking the timeline icon allowed access to a "Reset default locations" or something of that sense.  That action finally got "timeline" in the explorer.

*NOW* when I click on the ... in the exporer panel, timeline appears.

Of course, I have no idea to get it back into that secondary panel, since I never got it there in the first place...